# each individual label shoud to have individual address

Tags: python, tkinter

This app is stopwatch for each task. 
I created labels and buttons for every task by loop, but now problem is that all of the buttons refer to the last label. How can I solve it?

This is picture of how it looks right now:

Here my function of stopwatch and its dynamically changing label. But it addressing to the last one, when it shoud to change the label which is in the same row as clicked buttons.

```
def update_timeText():
        # We create our time string here
        timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
        # Update the timeText Label box with the current time
```

And this codeline address to the last

```
        labels[i].configure(text=timeString)
        # Call the update_timeText() function after 1 second
    root.after(1000, update_timeText)
# Simple status flag
state = False

#data from google table(only first 3 rows)
global i
for j in range(3): #Columns
for (i,cell) in enumerate(list_cells):
    i=i+1
    list_rows = cell.row
    values_list = sheet.row_values(list_rows)
    project = Label(root, text=values_list[j])
    items.append(project)
    project.grid(row=i, column=j)
    value=len(list_cells)
    for i in range(value):
        labels.append(Label(root,text="00:00:00"))
        labels[i].place(x=800,y=10+(30*i))
        Button(root,text="Start", command = start).place(x=870,y=10+(30*i))
        Button(root,text="Accept", command = pause).place(x=910,y=10+(30*i))

rows.append(items)
#run
update_timeText()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I blv your lines

```
for (i,cell) in enumerate(list_cells):
```

and

```
for i in range(value):
```

are conflicting .